# Navigating images giving 404 error in DXA 2.0

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

We are using DXA 2.0 with SDL Web8.5.We are publishing images to root structure group of the publication using custom template code but while we are trying to access the image using URL it always gives us 404 error.

I can see the entry of the image inside broker database.

Comment: How are you publishing (Topology Manager or old style Publishing) and is this an upgrade? The old Publication settings for image path and image URL used to influence where images are placed on servers as well as their URLs, but they no longer apply if using the "new style" publishing.

Comment: @AlvinReyes i m using topology manager for publishing content.The images are publishing to broker database.if i publish images in /system/assets structure group it rendered fine but if i publish it in / (root) it gives 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

DXA has no OOTB support for images (or other media items) which are not published to the default location for media item (i.e. the Multimedia URL specified on the Publicatiom).

Comment: is there any other way around to access images from ROOT of the website.

Comment: You could create a custom Controller which serves your images.

Comment: Ah, I thought DXA might ignore the default image location if the setup was using "new style" publishing. What if the image path was "\" and the image url was "/" (or empty, I forget what was valid). Would that work to serve images from the root with DXA?

Comment: Yes, it would, but it would also result in DXA expecting that your entire site consist of static content items (so, I wouldn't recommend it :-)